# Why does the SizedBox not constrain the Text widget width?

Tags: flutter

So I am making a simple messaging app and have run into the following problem:

I set the width of the SizedBox to 100, but when the child is a Text widget it overrides the SizedBox's width.

This widget is called from a ListView.builder in a different file.

Is there a different widget that I should be using for this, instead of a sizedbox?

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 100,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(14.0)),
            color: currentUserIsSender ? Styles.accentColor30 : Colors.grey.shade200,
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Text(
            message,
            softWrap: true,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Thanks

[Picture of app problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iki0H.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, `SizedBox` can set widget size only within the constrains set by the parent.
Many widgets, like Padding, want their child to occupy 100% of the space available to them. This makes sense, because if the child is smaller they wouldn't know where to put it.

If you want the child to be smaller than the parent you could use `Center` or `Align`, e.g. replace

```
Padding(
  child: SizedBox(
    width: 100,
    child: ...
    ),
  ),
);
```

with

```
Padding(
  child: Center(
    child: SizedBox(
      width: 100,
      child: ...
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

(for a chat app you might want to use `Align` rather than `Center`)

Related reading: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints

Comment: Perfect, thank you. That of course makes sense, I hadn't thought of that at all. I used Align and it works as desired.